# Choice of internal character encoding

Tags: c++, character-encoding, tokenize, delimiter

I have a simple tokenizer class in C++, that treats single array element values as delimiters. It fills a buffer until a delimiter is found. To support a larger set of delimiters including U+2192 Rightwards Arrow '→' rather than the sequence "->", I want to use a larger character set. Here are my conclutions so far

- UTF-8 will not give any more characters than US-ASCII as the tokenizer operates on array elements
- UTF-16 gives a lot more characteres that actually works, but it shares the property of being a multi-element encoding with UTF-8.
- UCS-2 Deprecated but would have been ideal for this case
- UCS-4 Never used in files
- UTF-32 Same as UCS-4 *possibly* multi-element in the future although not for now.

I want the source to be cross-platform between Windows (UTF-16) and Linux (UTF-8).

[EDIT]

I have decided to use UTF-16 internally. This supports a large set of symbols without using more than one element. Also I can avoid conversion on the Windows platform.

Comment: If you refuse to use a variable length encoding scheme then you don't have much choice. You only have UCS-2 and UTF-32 / UCS-4 available to you that can encode U+2192. It's news to me that UTF-32 might ever be variable length.

Comment: @CharlesBailey According to unicode.org: " Both Unicode and ISO 10646 have policies in place that formally limit future code assignment to the integer range that can be expressed with current UTF-16 (0 to 1,114,111). Even if other encoding forms (i.e. other UTFs) can represent larger intergers, these policies mean that all encoding forms will always represent the same set of characters." I think of the possibility that someone will change these policies in the future.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for why UTF-8 is not an option. Can you explain further?

Comment: @0x499602d2 Because it will break the tokenizer, which assumes one array element one symbol. UTF-8 is coded one symbol 1-4 elements.